# Какой корень в слове "Повар"

Tags: корень-слова

Всем привет :) У нас возник спор! Скажите, пожалуйста, какой корень в слове повар? -повар- или -вар-? Только, пожалуйста, укажите примеры. Потому что не очень понятно, с одной стороны увар, повар, поваренный, навар, казалось бы все просто вар вар вар, но ведь есть слова где корень кажется "повар" так как поваренная соль, поварская книга, поварешка…
ЗАРАНЕЕ ОГРОМНОЕ СПАСИБО!!

Answer (score 3):

по/вар-тот, кто вар/ит.

поварёшка- орудие повара. Словообразующая основа - повар, а корень всё равно -вар-.Корень - наименьшая морфема, несущая общий смысл ВСЕХ однокоренных слов.

по/вар/енн/ая, по/вар/ск/ая, по/вар/ёшк/а.

Answer (score 2):

Корень - "вар". 
Какие нужны примеры, если Вы их сами приводите? Все слова восходят к "варить", "варка".
На основании чего Вы полагаете, что в "поваренный" корень другой?

Answer (score 0):

В современном языке слово "повар" является непроизводным, хотя исторически оно образовано о глагола "варить" и имеет с ним общий исторический  корень ВАР. Но его способ образования "варить - повар" (префиксально-суффиксальный, приставка ПО + нулевой суффикс) уже не используется в современном словообразовании. Этот факт мешает нам выделить очевидный корень ВАР в слове "повар", здесь выделяется корень ПОВАР. 
От существительного  "повар" образуются слова "поваренок", "поварской". Слово "повАренный" ближе к  слову "варение"  (книга "по варению"), "поварешка" близка по смыслу к "поваривать", однако и они в словаре также числятся как непроизводные в силу той же причины.

ОТВЕТ 2. 
1. Автор вопроса, как и многие другие, СОМНЕВАЕТСЯ при морфемном разборе слова «повар». Неужели задача такая элементарная и наш ответ должен быть однозначным? А то получается так: «существует два мнения по этому вопросу: мое и неправильное».

1. Вот словарь Тихонова: сварщик есть, а повара нет. Почему? Потому что у сварщика прозрачная система образования, а у повара – мутная.
2. Берем толковый словарь. ВАРИТЬ - сущ. варка, -и, ж. (к 1,2 и 3 знач.)  и варение, -я, ср. (к 1, 2 и 3 знач.). || прил. варочный,  -ая, -ое (к 3 и 4 знач.; спец.). А вот существительного «повар» здесь почему-то нет. Это непроизводное слово? А непроизводные слова мы делим на морфемы?
3. Морфемный анализ бывает двух видов: Формально-структурный и формально-смысловой. 
   «Формально-структурный подход называют школьным, но он не является исключительно принадлежностью школьной практики. Аналогичный подход осуществлен в ряде научных изданий, например в «Словаре морфем русского языка» А. И. Кузнецовой и Т. Ф. Ефремовой, где утверждается, что «морфемный анализ МАЛО ЗАВИСИТ от словообразовательного. Формально-структурный подход связан с представлением большинства учащихся о слове как о веренице морфем, которые должны быть «опознаны» КАК УЖЕ ВСТРЕЧАВШИЕСЯ В ДРУГИХ СЛОВАХ». Главным при разборе становится эффект узнаваемости, внешнее сходство каких-то частей разных слов, и именно при таком разборе возможны следующие ошибки: клю-чик  и лет-чик, я-щик и свар-щик. При таком анализе: по-вар.
4. Формально-структурному подходу противопоставлен подход формально-смысловой. Главная установка данного подхода и алгоритм морфемного разбора выходят из трудов Г. О. Винокура и состоят В НЕРАЗРЫВНОСТИ МОРФЕМНОГО ЧЛЕНЕНИЯ И СЛОВООБРАЗОВАТЕЛЬНОГО РАЗБОРА. О том, что этот подход является целесообразным и даже единственно возможным, писали многие ученые и методисты на протяжении многих десятилетий.
5. Реально можно еще отметить подход, который назовем ГИБРИДНЫМ.  Он уже не хочет  считаться школьным и для убедительности обращается к словообразовательным цепочкам. Ящик от сварщика в этом случае отличить можно, но грубые ошибки в словообразовании наблюдаются постоянно, например: строчка (швейная) →строчить, а не строчить (шить на машинке)→ строчка, о чем прямо указывается в толковом словаре.
6. Разбираем по составу: по-мещ-ик, бел-к-а, пол-ян-а, по-един-ок, по-греб, о-сан-к-а, кур-нос-ый, воз-дух, бой-к-ий, без-дн-а, по-бед- а и т.д. Неправильно? А почему?
7. По поводу «похода». Имеем: ходить →ход (усечение основы), но «поход» не определяется через «ходить», у него отдельная статья, свои родственники: 
   ПОХОД ,  -а, м. 1. Передвижение войск или флота с какой-н. целью.  2. Дальние  передвижения войск в целях военных  действий,  а  также сами такие действия.  .  3.  Организованное путешествие или дальняя  прогулка,  а также вообще совместное движение  группы лиц с какой-н.  определенной целью. И т.д.|| прил. походный, -ая,  -ое (к  I, 2 и  3 знач.).

Comment: В каком современном? Ссылочку можно? Современнее Лопатина? Вот разбор по нему? http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%EF%EE%E2%E0%F0, В школьном словаре Текучёва и у Потихи тоже -вар-.

Comment: В двухтомнике Тихонова тоже производное, корень -вар-.

Comment: Поход, повод, потоп - что, все "непроизводные"?

Comment: Мой минус. Потому что неверный ответ.

Comment: У Тихонова в двухтомнике "повар" в гнезде от слова варить есть!!!  Т. 1, стр. 147. (гнездо №47 на букву В )

Answer (score 0):

Конечно, корень этого слова - вар. Он идет от старославянского глагола "варити", что означало "предостерегать, предупреждать". Этот корень можно найти и в немецком языке -  warnen, английском -warn, где и по сей день он сохранил свое изначальное толкование. В русском языке предлагается запомнить орфографию слова "предварительный" как непроверяемого.  Но его правописание легко объясняется упомянутым выше старославянским глаголом. Думаю,что корень слова  "варить" надо искать в этом красивом старославянском слове. Ведь, что означает варить?- Предотвратить порчу.